# How can I print whatever I see in Yacc/Bison?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, bison

I have a complicated Yacc file with a bunch of rules, some of them complicated, for example:

```
start: program
program: extern_list class
class: T_CLASS T_ID T_LCB field_dec_list method_dec_list T_RCB
```

The exact rules and the actions I take on them are not important, because what I want to do seems fairly simple: just print out the program as it appears in the source file, using the rules I define for other purposes. But I'm surprised at how difficult doing so is.

First I tried adding `printf("%s%s", $1, $2)` to the second rule above. This produced "��@P�@". From what I understand, the parsed text is also available as a variable, `yytext`. I added `printf("%s", yytext)` to every rule in the file and added `extern char* yytext;` to the top of the file. This produced `(null){void)1133331122222210101010--552222202020202222;;;;||||&&&&;;;;;;;;;;}}}}}}}}` from a valid file according to the language's syntax. Finally, I changed `extern char* yytext;` to `extern char yytext[]`, thinking it would not make a difference. The difference in output it made is best shown as a screenshot[image: Gibberish]

I am using Bison 3.0.2 on Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to echo the source to some output while parsing it, it is easiest to do that in the lexer.  You don't say what you ware using for a lexer, but you mention `yytext`, which is used by lex/flex, so I will assume that.

When you use flex to recognize tokens, the variable `yytext` refers to the internal buffer flex uses to recognize tokens.  Within the action of a token, it can be used to get the text of the token, but only temporarily -- once the action completes and the next token is read, it will no longer be valid.

So if you have a flex rule like:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*    { yylval.str = yytext, return T_ID; }
```

that likely won't work at all, as you'll have dangling pointers running around in your program; probably the source of the random-looking outputs you're seeing.  Instead you need to make a copy.  If you also want to output the input unchanged, you can do that here too:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*    { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); ECHO; return T_ID; }
```

This uses the flex macro `ECHO` which is roughly equivalent to `fputs(yytext, yyout)` -- copying the input to a `FILE *` called `yyout` (which defaults to `stdout`)

Answer (score 2):

If the first symbol in the corresponding right-hand side is a terminal, `$1` in a bison action means "the value of `yylval` produced by the scanner when it returned the token corresponding to that terminal. If the symbol is a non-terminal, then it refers to the value assigned to `$$` during the evaluation of the action which reduced that non-terminal. If there was no such action, then the default `$$ = $1` will have been performed, so it will pass through the semantic value of the first symbol in the reduction of that non-terminal.

I apologize if all that was obvious, but your snippet is not sufficient to show:

- what the semantic types are for each non-terminal;
- what the semantic types are for each terminal;
- what values, if any, are assigned to `yylval` in the scanner actions;
- what values, if any, are assigned to `$$` in the bison actions.

If any of those semantic types are not, in fact, character strings, then the `printf` will obviously produce garbage. (gcc might be able to warn you about this, if you compile the generated code with `-Wall`. Despite the possibility of spurious warnings if you are using old versions of flex/bison, I think it is *always* worthwhile compiling with `-Wall` and carefully reading the resulting warnings.)

Using `yytext` in a bison action is problematic, since it will refer to the text of the *last* token scanned, typically the look-ahead token. In particular, at the end of the input, `yytext` will be `NULL`, and that is what you will pick up in any reductions which occur at the end of input. glibc's `printf` implementation is nice enough to print `(null)` instead of segfaulting when your provide `(char*)0` to an argument formated as `%s`, but I don't think it's a great idea to depend on that.

Finally, if you do have a `char*` semantic value, and you assign `yylval = yytext` (or `yylval.sval = yytext;` if you are using unions), then you will run into another problem, which is that `yytext` points into a temporary buffer owned by the scanner, and that buffer may have completely different contents by the time you get around to using the address. So you always need to make a copy of `yytext` if you want to pass it through to the parser.

If what you *really* want to do is see what the parser is doing, I suggest you enable bison's [`yydebug` parser-trace feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing). It will give you a lot of useful information, without requiring you to insert printf's into your bison actions at all.